# Resolve folder for both debug and deployed vscode extensions

Tags: webpack, vscode-extensions

When you bundle resources (`asset/resource`) with Webpack 5 the files end up placed relative to the `publicPath` you specify in `webpack.config.js`

In my case that produces `{workspace}/dist/3fc1e0720620d224139a.jpg` in the debugger, and `{extension folder}/dist/3fc1e0720620d224139a.jpg` for an installed extension.

In extension code (Typescript, of course) we resolve the original name to the bundled name using `require(originalName)` and it duly returns `dist/3fc1e0720620d224139a.jpg`

The problem is I don't see how to write an expression that resolves to the folder containing this extension for both the debug host and the deployed extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this information is available from the `ExtensionContext` passed to the activate method. The extension root can be captured in the activate method and made available to other code.

However, if you need it in some library code it can be a pain to pass it. My solution was to define a `Metadata` class with a static `ExtensionContext` property, set the static `ExtensionContext` property in the `activate` method and import the class wherever I need the `ExtensionContext`.

If you need it before activate is called, for example while initialising a logger, you can get it like so

```
const extensionId = "pdconsec.vscode-print";
const extension = vscode.extensions.getExtension(extensionId)!;
const extensionPath = extension.extensionPath;
```